# Bootstrap overflowing doesn't work on grid columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, bootstrap-5

Using bootstrap 5.2.3

I'm sure this is not a problem with bootstrap but me not understanding the **flex system** and **overflow** fully.

As you can see below the first `div` has a fixed height of `100vh`. I want the **navigation bar**, **main content** and **footer** visible at all times.

The container with the images should be scrollable, hence the `overflow: scroll` style. But it breaks out of the parent and messes up the page. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the **grid** (`row` and `col` classes)

```
<div class="vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div>
    <h1>Navigation bar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-fill d-flex flex-column">
    <h1>Main content</h1>
    <div class="flex-fill d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row flex-fill">
        <div class="col-6">
          <p>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto consequuntur harum hic inventore laborum maiores necessitatibus nihil nobis officia optio perspiciatis quaerat quas quo reprehenderit rerum sequi, veritatis, vitae?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-wrap gap-2 overflow-scroll">
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
            <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum itaque nemo placeat sed voluptatum! Adipisci beatae debitis deleniti dignissimos doloremque, doloribus eius facere illo in, nisi nostrum quia repudiandae sit!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone in struggling to make a `overflow-scroll` work when working with Flex. However, if you take your time understanding the behavior of Flex, it can be done. I will take you through every step necessary to get  the result you're after.

Let's begin.

**Explaining the CSS**

Our HTML has three sections: `#header`, `#main` and `#footer`.

For the behavior you want it's best to first set the heights of the elements you want fixed (`#header` & `#footer`), and then calculate the remaining viewport height and apply it on your `main`.

We can easily do this using CSS variables. We first declare our `header` and  `footer` height's variables in the `:root` selector so they'll have a global scope, meaning we can use them anywhere in the style sheet.

```
:root {
  --headerHeight: 100px;
  --footerHeight: 100px;
}
```

Then we define `totalHeight` which we need later. Inside the `calc()` function we calculate the sum of `headerHeight` and `footerHeight` variables, which we can access using the `var()` function.

Since both are set on `100px`, `totalHeight` therefore will be `200px`.

```
--totalHeight: calc( var(--headerHeight) + var(--footerHeight) ) //200px
```

*It just makes your life easier if you want to change your `headerHeight` to say `150px`, not having to manually change `totalHeight` to be `250px`.*

We then apply the corresponding variables to the `#header` and `#footer` elements.

So how do we set the height for the remaining content, `#main`? Easy! We take the full viewport height `100vh` and subtract `totalHeight`. Done!

```
#main {
  height: calc(100vh - var(--totalHeight) );
}
```

**Explaining the HTML, utilizing Bootstrap**

The part that does all of the work is:

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column" id="main">
    <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
```

First we make the container a flex container with the `.d-flex` class. Because we want to stack our content within vertically we use the `.flex-column` class which will set the `flex-direction` to `column`.

Then comes our first `row`, which will automatically behave as a `flex item` as it is a direct child of our `flex` `container`. This means we can apply the `flex-grow` property to it by using the class `.flex-grow-1`. The beauty is that this `row` will now grow to fill available space, while allowing the remaining row(s) their necessary space.

So it's fully responsive, just like that!

All that's left to do is applying the class `.overflow-auto`, so *only* if this `row` overflows, a scrollbar will appear.

Take a look at the snippet below. Best is to view it with the `Full page` option, open your dev tools and toggle the responsive option. Now you can manually decrease the height of the page and watch the scrollbar appear as space runs out!

Also, [here's the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/vgkLaxop/)

```css
:root {
  --headerHeight: 100px;
  --footerHeight: 100px;
  --totalHeight: calc( var(--headerHeight) + var(--footerHeight) )
}

#header {
  height: var(--headerHeight);
}

#footer {
  height: var(--footerHeight);
}

#main {
  height: calc(100vh - var(--totalHeight) );
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="bg-primary py-4" id="header">
    <h1 class="text-center text-white m-0">Navigation bar</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column" id="main">
    <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
      <div class="col">
        <span>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto consequuntur harum hic inventore laborum maiores necessitatibus nihil nobis officia optio perspiciatis quaerat quas quo reprehenderit rerum sequi, veritatis, vitae?</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
        <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
        <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
        <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
        <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>
        <div class="border" style="background-color: green; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"><h5>Description</h5><img src="http://localhost:4545/blabla.png"></div>       
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum itaque nemo placeat sed voluptatum! Adipisci beatae debitis deleniti dignissimos doloremque, doloribus eius facere illo in, nisi nostrum quia repudiandae sit!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="bg-secondary py-4" id="footer">
    <h1 class="text-center text-white m-0">Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Other Solutions**

If your `header` and/or `footer` are not fixed in height, you can:

1. Set a `max-height` on the element that should scroll on overflow;
2. Utilize JavaScript to get the sum height of `header` and `footer` and  apply the remaining viewport height on `#main`.